# IE 7.0.5730.13 Problems with JSF Primefaces

Tags: jsf, user-interface, primefaces, internet-explorer-7

I've created an application using Primefaces. It works well on Firefox, Chrome and IE 9.
But there are many issues using the application on IE 7.0.5730.13.

**I'll list some problems:**

- DialogBox opens after clicking twice on a Button and page refresh
- DropDownBox is just a gray box, only after clicking on it the list opens, it just don't looks like a standard DropDownBox
- Tree table does not look well, some nodes pass over the tree table and just hang there

It looks that Primefaces is not compatible with IE 7.0.5730.13.

I researched a lot, but couldn't find anything on that issue.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

For all those, who still have problems with Dialog Boxes in IE Browsers

- remove "modal=true"
- set a fix width for your dialog box
- set a fix height for your dialog box

Answer (score 2):

For the most part you are correct, PrimeFaces and most any JSF component framework is not compatible with IE7.  Furthermore there are a few more advanced JSF components that utilize HTML5 features and may not work correctly in IE8 as well.

On that note, IE7 is an ancient browser and it is ridiculous if your client insists on support for it.  If they must use IE7 for some proprietary legacy software then you can always suggest using a proper browser for your software instead, like any supported version of Firefox, Chrome or Safari.

Answer (score 2):

Primefaces is [supposed to support IE 7](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2408) until version 3.5 (which is not supporting it anymore). If you are using this version just downgrade it to previous one. However, I can't be more agree with @maple_shaft.